# Unable to run commands such as hostnamectl in centos 7 Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, centos, systemd

I have a Centos 7 image running as a virtual machine (not as a Docker image).

When the VM boots up, it uses **`systemctl`** to start several services, one of which is my application that tries to set the `hostname` in the VM using command :

```
hostnamectl set-hostname my_host
```

But, It fails with this error :

```
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory.
```

I have checked that `dbus` is running by

```
ps aux| grep dbus

root      4555  0.0  0.0 112704   924 pts/4    S+   11:29   0:00 grep --color=auto dbus
dbus     25493  0.1  0.1  58084  2236 ?        Ss   10:54   0:03 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
```

Also, I can run `systemctl` commands to start and stop some services, but trying to start **`firewalld`** also generates an error.

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

***EDIT***
I found the issue, system_bus_socket was in /run/dbus not in /var/run/dbus. Creating a symlink to /var/run/dbus allowed hostnamectl to run succcessfully.

However, my question is, why was system_bus_socket placed in /run/dbus originally?

Comment: You should paste output of `ps` command. It would be helpful.